# Send a NFT together with Tokens

Tags: token, nft, erc20

Is there a way to send an 1155 or 731 nft in one transaction together with a token(erc-20)
and if yes could someone provide an example

Answer (score 0):

You can create a muticall contract that wraps both token transfers into one transaction.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract MyContract {
  IERC20 erc20Token = IERC20(address(0x123));
  IERC721 nftCollection = IERC721(address(0x456));


  function sendFromThisContract(address to, uint256 erc20Amount, uint256 nftId) external {
    erc20Token.transfer(to, erc20Amount);
    nftCollection.transferFrom(address(this), to, nftId);
  }

  function sendFromUser(address to, uint256 erc20Amount, uint256 nftId) external {
    erc20Token.transferFrom(msg.sender, to, erc20Amount);
    nftCollection.transferFrom(msg.sender, to, nftId);
  }
}
```

In case of `sendFromUser()`, the user needs to send additional 2 transactions to be able to perform this action:

1. to the ERC20 token contract, approving `MyContract` to operate the user's tokens
2. to the NFT collection contract, approving `MyContract` to operate the user's specific token ID (or all tokens)

---

It is not technically possible to transfer multiple tokens (with different contract addresses) in one transaction without an intermediary or without the approvals. This is because when you're sending a token, you're sending a transaction to the token/collection contract. And by design, a transaction can have only one recipient.

Comment: the transaction should only have 1 receipant

Comment: @NoVa It does have only one recipient - the `MyContract` address.